# Speeding up XML to MySQL with Nokogiri in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I'm writing large amounts of data from XML feeds to my MySQL database in my Rails 3 app using Nokogiri. Everything is working fine but it's slower than I would like.

Is there any way to speed up the process? This is simplified version of the script I'm using:

```
url = "http://example.com/urltoxml"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
doc.xpath("//item").each do |record|

  guid = record.xpath("id").inner_text
  price = record.xpath("price").inner_text
  shipping = record.xpath("shipping").inner_text

  data = Table.new(
    :guid => guid,
    :price => price,
    :shipping => shipping
  )
  if price != ""
    data.save
  end

end
```

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is not from parsing XML, but is that you insert the records one by one in the DB, which is very costly.

Unfortunately, AFAIK Rails does not provide a native way to mass-insert records. There once was a gem that did it, but I can't get my hand back on it.

"[Mass inserting data in Rails without killing your performance](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/)", though, provides helpful insights on how to do it manually.

If you go this way, don't forget to process your nodes in batches if you don't want to end with a single 999-bazillion-rows INSERT statement.

Comment: Rails doesn't do batch imports, but you can wrap the whole thing in a transaction, which would likely increase the speed.

Comment: Thnx m_x. I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up but I would if I could. I'm going to read the article you mentioned. I will also look into transactions, thnx mitch.

Comment: @MitchDempsey i don't get it, why wrapping the thing in a transaction would improve performance ? Plus,  each save is already wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: @m_x you would wrap the whole `each` loop in a transaction, so all rows would be submitted at the same time.

Comment: @MitchDempsey AFAIK it won't. A transaction just ensures that every operation within its boundaries is successful, it won't magically transform all your save operations into a single one... You'll just have a bunch of single row inserts inside a transaction.